# places.getLatLng() returning null though places.getName() is not returning null

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-places-api

I have been trying to get the latlng after clicking a place from autocomplete the weird thing is that `places.getName()` is working fine but `place.getLatLng()` returning null. What should I do to solve this I am new to google maps and places API!

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE_FROM) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i("shipadd", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            from_edit_txt.setText(place.getName());
            origin = place.getLatLng();
            Log.e("origin_destarray", "" + place.getLatLng());
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i("shipadd", status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    } else if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE_TO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i("shipadd", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + ", " + place.getId());
            to_edit_txt.setText(place.getName());
```

I want the following code to return the lattudes and logitude of the place that i select in the autocomplete activity

Comment: make sure you have your location settings enabled

Comment: location settings is enabled

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Previously the Places SDK for Android was made available through Google Play Services. 
**The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android is deprecated and Google will turn it off by July 29, 2019.**

But, the new version of the Places SDK for Android is distributed as a static client library.
The dependency for the new SDK client library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

You can use either one of the two ways of adding Google places autocomplete in android application:

```
 1) Either embed a AutocompleteSupportFragment
 OR
 2) Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity.
```

I created a demo app by embedding a AutocompleteSupportFragment bellow :-

```
package com.places_api_demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.listener.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import static com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.LAT_LNG;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG = "placeautocomplete";
TextView txtView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtView = findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    // Initialize Places.
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "REPLACE YOUR API KEY HERE");
    // Create a new Places client instance.
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    // Specify the types of place data to return.
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            txtView.setText(place.getName()+"\n"+place.getId()+"\n"+ place.getLatLng());
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " +  place.getLatLng());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
}
```

[image: The debug results display the location details of the searched place]

Also its important to specify the type of place data to return

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```

[For more details related to Place Data fields please refer here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.Field)

Comment: Thanks i didn't mention  Place.Field.LAT_LNG, my bad thanks for the help! you are lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I was facing and finally I came to know that we need to request `Place.Field.LAT_LNG`.

**This function will open autocomplete**

```
private void openGetLocation() {

    // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to
    // return after the user has made a selection.
    List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG,Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

    // Start the autocomplete intent.
    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
            .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

**Get the place details here `onActivityResult`**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
        locationEd.setText(place.getLatLng().toString());
    } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
        Toast.makeText(this, status.getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Here I have requested three things `Place.Field.LAT_LNG` ,`Place.Field.ID`, `Place.Field.NAME`